# How to get the top 10 highest values Json

Tags: java

So I wanted to make a list of top 10 donators for a java application and was going to use Json to store the data for that.

So the Json basically looks like this:

```
{
    "donators": {
        "donator1":5,
        "donator2":13,
        "donator3":8
    }
}
```

Now I was wondering if there is any sort of efficient way in how I could store the variable name and variable value in a list and then sort them with the collections method to display the top 10 best donators.

Would I use a hasmap for this? Also it must be dynamic, I need to be able to increment the values of the variables.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: JSON is a data transfer format. It shouldn't have anything to do with how you sort Java objects. A more appropriate representation of that list of donators would be [{"name": "John", "donation": 13}, {"name": "Jack", donation: 11}]: it's a list, of donators. Just what you actually want. But your question is basically equivalent to "I want to sort bananas by their size, and I've decided to use a truck to do that". A truck can be useful to transport bananas, but it has nothing to do with sorting them.

Comment: How are you parsing the JSON? How are you representing the JSON in Java? What attempts have you tried?

Comment: @JBNizet Okay sorry I didn't meant that I wanted to use JSON to make the actual list, I just meant how should I properly store the data so I can easily access it? I want name and donation to be linked to each other but I am not sure on how to do that in a clean way.

Comment: Well, define a Donator class, with two fields: name and donation. Create a List<Donator>, sort it, keep the 10 first elements. You can then choose to serialize this list of 10 donators to JSON.

Comment: @JBNizet I am so dumb, how could I have not thought abotu that lol, thanks a lot mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by creating a donator class with two fields, thanks to JB Nizet